# Implementing social media login with grails

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, oauth, pac4j

I'm trying to implement Google/LinkedIn registration/login with grails.
I've started with spring security rest plugin and this is my application.groovy file:

```
oauth {
                frontendCallbackUrl = { String tokenValue -> "http://localhost:8080/auth/success?token=${tokenValue}" } 
                google {
                    client = org.pac4j.oauth.client.Google2Client 
                    key = "93928074758-p687srmuti88m9ud6k16ngaeenglac5n.apps.googleusercontent.com" 
                    secret = "p3IF_jei8YIv2FF7nYjqPBTM" 
                    scope = org.pac4j.oauth.client.Google2Client.Google2Scope.EMAIL_AND_PROFILE 
                    defaultRoles = [] 
                }
                linkedin {
                    client = org.pac4j.oauth.client.LinkedIn2Client
                    key = "77krf1ww7mhbx7" 
                    secret = "KYCZT14ZVyts8sAM"
                    scope = "r_emailaddress"
                    defaultRoles = [] 
                }


            }
```

I was able to fetch the user data gathered with Google, but with LinkedIn there is a problem with the URL to get the info.

Here is the XML I get in response from LinkedIn:

```
<error>
<status>410</status>
  <timestamp>1573061835025</timestamp>
  <request-id>7XT0T4X984</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs</message>
</error>
```

Do you have any tips to implement this?
Can you see any missing parameter at the LinkedIn config?

Thanks in advance.

PD: Here is the plugin documentation I'm using: https://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/

Comment: "...but with LinkedIn there is a problem with the URL to get the info" - Can you provide any info on what that problem is or how it manifests?

Comment: Hello Jeff, thanks for the answer, let me add more details about the issue.